# Python - Cloudant Get Changes

Tags: python, cloudant

I'm using the library Cloudant in order to gather documents from a Cloudant Database. Everytime I run the python script I get all the documents but I would like to retrieve only the documents added from the last execution of the script, in other words a get_changes function.

I have searched for an answer but it not seems to be easely to find.

Thaks for any help,

Filippo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `changes()` method. Keep track of the last sequence id, and restart from there to retrieve only the unseen changes.

```
# Iterate over a "normal" _changes feed
changes = db.changes()
for change in changes:
    print(change)

# ...time passes
new_changes = db.changes(since=changes.last_seq)
for new_change in new_changes:
    print(new_change)
```

If you also want the doc body, you can pass `include_docs=True`.

See https://github.com/cloudant/python-cloudant/blob/master/src/cloudant/database.py#L458

If you want to capture only new additions (as opposed to all changes), you can either create a filter function in a db design doc along the lines of:

```
function(doc, req) {
    // Skip deleted docs
    if (doc._deleted) {
        return false;
    }
    // Skip design docs
    if (doc._id.startsWith('_design')) {
        return false;
    }

    // Skip updates
    if (!doc._rev.startsWith('1-')) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

and apply that to the changes feed:

```
new_changes = db.changes(since=changes.last_seq, filter='myddoc/myfilter'):
    # do stuff here
```

but probably as easy to simply get all the changes and filter in the Python code.

Filter functions: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/guides/replication_guide.html#filtered-replication

Comment: Yes, after the post I tried tha method and it works fine. I have to edit the question because what I would like to do is to retrieve only the additional documents uploaded after the last sequence id. The scripts you have posted return back also the design documents and the documents modification, but I'm not interested in those results. By the way, thank you for the answer

Comment: Thank you so much xpqz, your comments help a lot